# PHP - Check either an array element has a key by default or it's key was automated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I know my question is a bit odd, but I need this for a function I'm writing. 
I've been struggling with this for a while.

Supposed I have the following array:

```
$array = array(
    "column1" , 
    "column2" , 
    "column3"=>"value3" , 
    "7"=>"value5" , 
    "8"=>"value6" 
);
```

$array has elements with keys, set by default, and elements without keys.
I know that elements with no keys will have numeric automated keys set to them.

I'm trying to write a function that will convert this array to the following MYSQL select statement:

```
SELECT `column1` , `column2` , `column3` , `1` , `0` FROM table WHERE column3 = 'value3' AND 1 = 'value5' AND 0 = 'value6';
```

**Mysql table names can be numeric.**

I'm stuck in my function at the part where I have to check if the array element has a key set by php or sent by the user.

The form of my function so far:

```
//Function that converts WHERE simple statement to Array
function arrayToQuery($array){
    if(is_array($array)){
        $selectedColumns = array();
        $whereColumns = array();
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            //This is where I'm stuck, I can't write the is_automated() function
            if(!is_automated($key)){
                $whereColumns[$key] = $value;
            }
            $selectedColumns[] = $key;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT " . join(",", $selectedColumns) . " WHERE ";
        foreach($whereColumns as $column=>$value){
            $sql .= $column . " = " . $value . " AND ";
        }
        $sql .= " 1=1 ";
        return $sql;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm stuck at the is_automated() function, I'm not able to check either key was automated or not.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if understand but why can't you just do:  if($value){
                $whereColumns[$key] = $value;
            }

Comment: Well in this case the if condition will be always true, since all array elements has values ... I don't think you understood my problem @maque

Comment: what criteria determines whether or not a key is user generated?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to know @dbinns66

Comment: If you don't know what distinguishes user v. code generated data in your own program, I don't think anyone else will be able to help you...  Also see @John McMahon's answer, your example data would never be able to generate your sample query...

Comment: @dbinns66 This is all my code, there is nothing hidden. I'm simply trying to code a function that converts an array to a MYSQL select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to keep this structure, you're probably going to want to create a class to handle this. In PHP 5, classes can extend [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php), leading to unique use cases such as the one you are describing.

Example:

```
<?php
class MySQLArray extends ArrayIterator {
    public $container,$noKeySet,$current, $flags;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->setFlags(1);
    }
    
    public function offsetSet($offset,$value) {
        if(!isset($offset)) {
            $this->noKeySet[] = $value;
        }
        return parent::offsetSet($offset,$value);
    }
    
    public function isAutomated($key) {
        if(isset($this->noKeySet[$key])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$array = new MySQLArray();
$array[] = "column1"; 
$array[] = "column2";
$array["column3"] = "value3"; 
$array[7] = "value5" ;
$array[8] ="value6";

function arrayToQuery($array){
        $selectedColumns = array();
        $whereColumns = array();
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){ gettype($value);
            //This is where I'm stuck, I can't write the is_automated() function
            if(!$array->isAutomated($key)){
                $whereColumns[$key] = $value;
            }
            $selectedColumns[] = $key;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT " . join(",", $selectedColumns) . " WHERE ";
        foreach($whereColumns as $column=>$value){
            $sql .= $column . " = " . $value . " AND ";
        }
        $sql .= " 1=1 ";
        return $sql;
    return false;
}

?>
```

Unfortunately you will not be able to use a lot of the quick array implementors or any shorthand because you are interfacing with an object.

## However

A better ultimate solution would be to rely on something other than an array. Depending on your use case (not specified), there could be any number of ways to do this instead of a singular array.

For starters, why have numbers as SQL columns? It's not very explanatory and doesn't seem scalable to me. If you have a reason to have numbers as columns, a relatively easy fix depending on your stage of development could be to put a qualifier in front of each number (say, stage_1, stage_2, etc.) then put the qualifier in the array.

As it stands, your arrays will do funky things if you try to put numerical keys and values together. So I don't repeat what others have posted, I am going to recommend you review the great explanations as to why this is not sustainable.

Comment: You should refactor your answer  because the  key/value  pairs are  inconsistent.  Half way through  it changes to value/key pairing which is the root of th OP's problem.

Comment: I answered the core question, which is an interesting one to me, and that is: How to "Check either an array element has a key by default or it's key was automated". Your answer has good points and speaks to a fundamental flaw in the code and logic. It is worth reading but I tried to answer the question directly and DID include a caveat. I will edit to recommend that readers read other posts too to understand WHY this is not sound code.

Answer (score 2):

PHP automatically converts "0" to an integer, so AFAIK, there is no way to check if a key was automatically assigned.

Why don't you use a `null` or `false` value?

```
$array = array(
    "column1" => null,
    "column2" => null,
    "column3"=>"value3" , 
    "1"=>"value5" , 
    "0"=>"value6" 
);
```

The only problem with `null` is how do you determine when the user wants `IS NULL` in the query.  In that case, you could use `false` with strict checking `if ($value === false)`.

You should also be looking into using prepared statements with your query generation in my opinion, to avoid the possibility of injections.

**Update:**

If developers are going to be using this, they probably shouldn't be using an array.  You should have a class and a method for loading this.  For example:

```
public function addField($name, $value=false) {
   $this->fields[$name] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I guess if can't find an answer I'll go ahead and do as you said, it's just that I was trying to write this function with to be user friendly. This function will be used later by multiple developers... Not this exact one though ..

Comment: Running a quick test verifies that PHP does convert a string key "0" or "1" to integer keys, so you lose the ability to test for integer vs string on those.

Comment: @AymanAbiAoun, developers should use a class, not the direct array.  So you could make a method like I have shown in my update.

Comment: @Devon well actually the function I wrote is part of a class called Table that contains all other function that ease MYSQL queries. This function is part of the Select function. I'm using ADODB for the executions.

Comment: Okay, well how you have your array structured is a bit confusing when it comes to being analyzed, just remember that.  You'll have some column names as keys and some column names as values.  From printing out the array, someone should be able to determine which is which easily.

Comment: @Devon my bad I lacked further explanation ... The real function is called Select. Developers will write: 
    $tableObj = new Table("tableName");
    $tableObj->Select($array);
They are the one that provide the array. Example:  
   
    $tableObj = new Table("tableName");
    $result = $tableObj->Select("id","name"=>"devon","type"=>"human");

The Select function will execute the following query: 
SELECT id,name,type from tableName WHERE name = devon AND type = human;

Comment: Yes, it looks nice and neat there, but from a development standpoint, what you're truly passing is `[0 => "id", "name" => "devon", "type" => "human" ]` which isn't very neat.

Answer (score 2):

Your example array is overwriting the first 2 elements. I ran this:

```
$array = array(
        "column1" ,
        "column2" ,
        "column3"=>"value3" ,
        "1"=>"value5" ,
        "0"=>"value6"
);
print_r($array);
```

And got this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value6
    [1] => value5
    [column3] => value3
)
```

Comment: Interesting, I deleted my answer because of this, it seems PHP converts the key to an integer even when it is defined as a string.

Comment: @Devon I was thinking along the same lines at first, but then decided to do a little sanity check on the actual array contents.

Comment: @JohnMcMahon well Devon was right, I had to change keys 0 and 1 to 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that in PHP, there is no "keyless" array. We can write array in our code without keys, only values, but the interpreter automatically assigns numerical index upon reading/parsing.

This

`array ( 'one', 'two', 'three' )`

... is exactly the same as this:

`array ( 0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three' )`

Conclusion: array key, always exists in PHP, whether You wrote it or not. If You don't put keys in Your code *(which is 100% legit) the keys still exists (must exist) and will be (considered as) numerical.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to obey the  conventions  and style of your own code. You have set  the table($array) as key/value pairs in the following. You have also used the => operator and quotes " " . But then you are losing it because of inconsistent behavior in your code writing.  Why are the array elements suddenly written differently half way through?

```
$array = array(
"column1" , 
"column2" , 
"column3"=>"value3" , 
"7"=>"value5" , 
"8"=>"value6"
```

);

With the operators and delimitation that are missing and necessary for the code to be read and parsed correctly should be written as:

```
$array = array(
"column1" => "" , 
"column2" => "" , 
"column3" => "value3" , 
"7" => "value5" , 
"8" => "value6" 
);
```

This keeps the convention you have set and allows you to iterate without knowing anything about the keys.

Also do not use NULL in your array. Empty strings and NULL are not the same thing:

```
$array = array(
"column1" => null,
"column2" => null,
"column3"=>"value3" , 
"1"=>"value5" , 
"0"=>"value6"
```

);

Will cause you pain because the elements

```
$array["column1"] = null;
$array["column2"] = null;
```

will return false for use of isset() and empty() and only resspond to is_null which is a pain in the butt for any developer following you.

Speaking  of which using the following coding style will make it less likely to make the same mistake again and more easy to understand where you went wrong.

```
$array["column1"] = "";  // without quotes $array["column1"] = ; will error
$array["column2"] = ""; //   swapping $array[] = "column2"; breaks key/value pair
$array["column3"] = "value3";
$array["7"] = "value5";
$array["8"] = "value6";
```